# Debugging sometimes is extremely slow in IDEA

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea

Sometimes debugging our purely local desktop application in IDEA 2021.2.4 with Java 11 becomes incredible slow, especially Step Over (F8) or (to a less extend) Step Into (F7). But sometimes even pressing Resume (F9) after having hit some breakpoints is extremely slow while the CPU fan runs at full power (what takes 1s to start normally takes multiple minutes). Stopping usually halts in JDK code, e.g. class loading. I've already verified the breakpoints, but there are just a handful of normal Java Line breakpoints without any conditions.  Especially when pressing Resuming other things mentioned in the IDEA FAQ like toString evaluation or Java Type Renderers should not matter, isn't it? Even pausing, disabling all breakpoints, resuming makes no difference.

Any idea how to determine what causes the CPU to heat?

Comment: Intellij IDEA as IDE itself consumes a lot of power cycles and CPU. Debugging is the cherry on cake.

Comment: Hard to say. If this is a complex application with many threads, make sure you're not suspending all threads. Right click on a break point and make sure that "thread" is selected instead of "all".

Comment: It seems to start while debugging. Stopping the app and restarting the debugger usually is fast, but after some stepping it often gets slow again.

Comment: Does https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799 help?

Comment: No, that article I meant with IDEA FAQ.

Comment: If you see high CPU usage by IntelliJ IDEA process, please provide a CPU snapshot per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235. You can also check debugger logs to see what happens when you step over: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799. toString can still affect performance, try disabling all the options mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: Restarting the IDE is not helpful during debug, because with a fresh launch it works fast again.

Comment: You don't need to restart it, just run it with the debugger logs for a day until the issue occurs again.